# Descending SQL Statement GridViewControl Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have created a database using visual studio and a gridview to show the data. I am trying to display the data in descending order. I have previousley created a FillBy method to sort the data in ascending order when prompted (SELECT personID, name, age FROM dbo.person BY FillByage).

I have tried (SELECT personID, name, age FROM dbo.person BY FillByage DESC) but this produces an error.

Does anyone know how to write a successful descending SQL statement?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL Statement should be:

```
SELECT personID, name, age
FROM dbo.person
ORDER BY FillByage DESC
```

Notice the `ORDER BY`, not just `BY`

Based on the image provided, it appears that you do not have a space between FillByage and the `DESC` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `ORDER BY` (not just `BY`)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx